# Multiple CASE statements in SQL requires formatting

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am looking for a better way to write this case statement.  The scenario is like this

Weekly - DateFrom is a Monday and DateTo is a Sunday
Monthly - Whole month
Yearly - Whole Year

However, if there is an override date which limits the weekly, monthly and yearly date range then these should be taken into account.  The following works but looks horrible

```
 SELECT @dateMax =
       CASE @dateFrequency
            WHEN 'Daily' THEN @dateMax
            WHEN 'Weekly' THEN  
                CASE WHEN  @OverrideDateMax < DATEADD(WK, 1, (DateAdd(d, -(DatePart(dw,@dateMin) -1), @dateMin))) 
                    THEN DATEADD(DAY,1,@OverrideDateMax)
                ELSE 
                    DATEADD(WK, 1, (DateAdd(d, -(DatePart(dw,@dateMin) -1), @dateMin))) 
                END 
            WHEN 'Monthly' THEN 
                CASE WHEN @OverrideDateMax < DATEADD(MONTH,1,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @dateMax), 0))
                    THEN DATEADD(DAY,1, @OverrideDateMax)
                ELSE 
                    DATEADD(MONTH,1,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @dateMax), 0))
                END 
            WHEN 'Yearly' THEN 
                CASE WHEN  @OverrideDateMax < DATEADD(Year,1, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(Year, 0, @dateMax),0))
                    THEN DATEADD(DAY,1, @OverrideDateMax)
                ELSE                        
                    DATEADD(Year,1, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(Year, 0, @dateMax),0))
                END 
        END,
        @dateMin = 
        CASE @dateFrequency
            WHEN 'Daily' THEN @dateMin
            WHEN 'Weekly' THEN 
                CASE WHEN  @OverrideDateMin > DateAdd(d,  -(DatePart(dw,@dateMin) -1), @dateMin) 
                    THEN @OverrideDateMin 
                ELSE 
                    DateAdd(d,  -(DatePart(dw,@dateMin) -1), @dateMin)
                END 
            WHEN 'Monthly' THEN 
                CASE WHEN  @OverrideDateMin > @dateMin  THEN 
                    @OverrideDateMin
                ELSE 
                    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @dateMin), 0)
                END
            WHEN 'Yearly' THEN 
                CASE WHEN  @OverrideDateMin > @dateMin  THEN 
                    @OverrideDateMin
                ELSE    
                    DATEADD(Year, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, @dateMin), 0)
                END
        END
```

Comment: I think this is better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is it right that your overrides for min just examine `@dateMin` (for month and year) whereas in the max case it considers the value that would have been computed in the absence of an override? I find the asymmetry surprising.

Answer (score 0):

If you're logic is sound and you're happy with it, then I'd be inclined to just tidy the formatting and add some explanatory comments.

```
 SELECT @dateMax =
       CASE @dateFrequency
            WHEN 'Daily' 
            -- When Daily, always take the date max   
            THEN @dateMax
            WHEN 'Weekly'
            -- When Weekly Special logic applies   
            THEN    CASE
                        -- if an override date is specified which is less than (describe function)    
                        WHEN @OverrideDateMax < DATEADD(WK, 1, (DateAdd(d, -(DatePart(dw,@dateMin) -1), @dateMin))) 
                        -- the use one day beyond the override
                        THEN DATEADD(DAY,1,@OverrideDateMax)
                        -- otherwise use (describe function)
                        ELSE DATEADD(WK, 1, (DateAdd(d, -(DatePart(dw,@dateMin) -1), @dateMin))) 
                    END 
            WHEN 'Monthly' 
            THEN    CASE 
                        WHEN @OverrideDateMax < DATEADD(MONTH,1,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @dateMax), 0))
                        THEN DATEADD(DAY,1, @OverrideDateMax)
                        ELSE DATEADD(MONTH,1,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @dateMax), 0))
                    END 
            WHEN 'Yearly' 
            THEN    CASE 
                        WHEN  @OverrideDateMax < DATEADD(Year,1, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(Year, 0, @dateMax),0))
                        THEN DATEADD(DAY,1, @OverrideDateMax)
                        ELSE DATEADD(Year,1, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(Year, 0, @dateMax),0))
                    END 
        END
```

There are a couple of common functions there which could be extracted and put into Scalar Value functions which might improve readability. e.g.

This appears twice

```
DATEADD(WK, 1, (DateAdd(d, -(DatePart(dw,@dateMin) -1), @dateMin)))
```

You could put in

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[WeekDateMax]
(
    @dateMin DateTime
)
RETURNS DateTime
AS
BEGIN

    RETURN DATEADD(WK, 1, (DateAdd(d, -(DatePart(dw,@dateMin) -1), @dateMin)))
END
GO
```

And then simplify you're date max weekly block to

```
THEN    CASE
        -- if an override date is specified which is less than (describe function)    
        WHEN @OverrideDateMax < [dbo].[WeekDateMax](@dateMin)
        -- the use one day beyond the override
        THEN DATEADD(DAY,1,@OverrideDateMax)
        -- otherwise use (describe function)
        ELSE [dbo].[WeekDateMax](@dateMin)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would break it up like this.

```
DECLARE @WeekMin AS datetime = DateAdd(d,  -(DatePart(dw,@dateMin) -1), @dateMin);
DECLARE @WeekMax AS datetime = DATEADD(WK, 1, (DateAdd(d, -(DatePart(dw, @dateMin) -1), @dateMin)));
DECLARE @MonthMin AS datetime = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @dateMin), 0);
DECLARE @MonthMax AS datetime = DATEADD(MONTH,1,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @dateMax), 0));
DECLARE @YearMin AS datetime = DATEADD(Year, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, @dateMin), 0);
DECLARE @YearMax AS datetime = DATEADD(Year,1, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(Year, 0, @dateMax),0));

SET @dateMin = CASE @dateFrequency
                    WHEN 'Daily' THEN @dateMin
                    WHEN 'Weekly' THEN @WeekMin
                    WHEN 'Monthly' THEN @MonthMin
                    WHEN 'Yearly' THEN @YearMin
               END;
SET @dateMin = CASE WHEN @OverrideDateMin > @dateMin 
                    THEN @OverrideDateMin
                    ELSE @dateMin
               END;

SET @dateMax = CASE @dateFrequency
                    WHEN 'Daily' THEN @dateMax
                    WHEN 'Weekly' THEN @WeekMax
                    WHEN 'Monthly' THEN @MonthMax
                    WHEN 'Yearly' THEN @YearMax
               END;
SET @dateMax = CASE WHEN @OverrideDateMax < @dateMax 
                    THEN @OverrideDateMax
                    ELSE @dateMax
               END;
```

Comment: Performance wise would that be affected as its calling all the date manipulation in one go, whereas case statements only get called when desired?

Comment: @ninjaplayer, If your performance requirements are so tight that a few dateadds matter why do you ask about formatting?